# Program to calculate how much a process is swapping in linux

Tags: c, linux, performance, memory-management

I have been working on several small C programs to measure system performance and utilization. Calculating things like CPU utilization seems to be fairly easy, but now I'm working on a way to assign different processes a "score" based on how much they are swapping, or being swapped.

Basically, I'm trying to see which process might be causing the system to thrash.

I'm looking into using cgroups, specifically the `/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/.../memory.stat` file. Cgroups are ubiquitous in my environment. These are the fields available to me:

```
cache 997203968
rss 4679643136
mapped_file 494514176
pgpgin 454901845
pgpgout 453515896
pgfault 741229338
pgmajfault 250671
inactive_anon 74235904
active_anon 4605407232
inactive_file 815894528
active_file 181309440
unevictable 0
hierarchical_memory_limit 9223372036854775807
total_cache 997203968
total_rss 4679643136
total_mapped_file 494514176
total_pgpgin 454901845
total_pgpgout 453515896
total_pgfault 741229338
total_pgmajfault 250671
total_inactive_anon 74235904
total_active_anon 4605407232
total_inactive_file 815894528
total_active_file 181309440
total_unevictable 0
```

I was thinking I could sample the pgpgout field over a few seconds and see how much a process is swapping. I want to assign a score based on which processes are the worst offenders. Any other suggestions are welcome!

Comment: What worth would the amount of swapped memory be? There is no simple relation between performance and swapped memory on Linux. Worse: it is not under control of the program whether its pages are actually swapped. What does it tell you about a program if another program uses more RAM than available?

Comment: I was thinking more about the rate at which a process is swapping. However, I see what you're saying, swapping isn't necessarily detrimental. I suppose a better question is how can I tell if a process or cgroup is causing thrash?

Comment: As I already wrote: it is **not** the process which is swapping, but the OS! The conditions are not under control of the process. Heck, Linux even swapps if there **is** enough RAM if it thinks buffers are more important. And most of the time it is right.